# How to Jump by Button UI using Character Controller in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am calling JUMP function from a UI Button but unable to jump using Character Collider provided by Unity. Can someone please help me where am i going wrong?

PlayerMovement Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PlayerControllerCC : MonoBehaviour
{
    public FixedJoystick moveJoystick;

    CharacterController _charController;
    private Vector3 v_movement;
    private Animator _animator;

    public float moveSpeed = 0.1f;
    public float gravity = 0.5f;
    public float jumpForce = 0.5F;
    private float originalstepOffset;

    private float InputX;
    private float InputZ;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        moveSpeed = 0.1f;
        gravity = 0.5f;
        jumpForce = 0.5F;

        _charController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        originalstepOffset = _charController.stepOffset;
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        InputX = moveJoystick.Horizontal;
        InputZ = moveJoystick.Vertical;

        isWalking();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        playerMovement();
    }

    void playerMovement()
    {
        //Check Gravity
        if (_charController.isGrounded)
        {
            _charController.stepOffset = originalstepOffset;
            v_movement.y = -0.5f;
        }
        else
        {
            _charController.stepOffset = 0;
            v_movement.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        

        //player movement
        v_movement = new Vector3(InputX * moveSpeed, v_movement.y, InputZ * moveSpeed);

        float magnitute = Mathf.Clamp01(v_movement.magnitude);
        v_movement.Normalize();
        _charController.Move(v_movement * magnitute);

        Vector3 lookDir = new Vector3(v_movement.x, 0, v_movement.z);

        //Set rotation facing after player movement 
        if ((lookDir.x != 0) && (lookDir.z != 0))
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookDir);
        }
                
    }

    void isWalking()
    {
        if (InputX == 0 && InputZ == 0)
        {
            _animator.SetBool("isWalking", false);
        }
        else
        {
            _animator.SetBool("isWalking", true);
        }
    }

    public void Attack()
    {
        _animator.SetTrigger("isAttacking");
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if (_charController.isGrounded)
        {
            v_movement.y = jumpForce * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }

}
```

When button is clicked in UI it called the JUMP function. I am not using keyboard but FixedJoyStick hence using button to jump.
My Game looks like this and the UI. The up arrow key is the jump button.

[The Game button Up Arrow Jump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuMaq.png)

[Calling Jump Function in Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ASu6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lays on the OnClick() function of the button, it is interacting with the script but the script itself is not attached to any character in this case. What you did works when the script works by itself no matter where is attached (e.g. when you call all the objects with a tag).

What you need to do is to link the object which has the script to the OnClick() in the editor, then select from the dropdown menu the script component and then call the function you want.

Like This.

[Image link since I'm new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNDjf.png)

Notice how what is linked are the Game Objects and then the script is selected.